# Sorting Custom Object Price Values in Ascending and Descending order

Tags: java

I have Price Values like below in String format getting from Custom object

2,000,3,000,5,000,300,-,600,-,507,-

I want to Sort the above Price Values in Ascending and Descending order

Could any one help?

I have tried this:

```
 Comparator<Cars> comparator = new Comparator<Cars>() {

          @Override
          public int compare(Cars object1, Cars object2) {
          // return Float.compare(Integer.parseInt(object1.getPrice()), Integer.parseInt(object2.getPrice()));


              String price1=object1.getPrice().replaceAll(",","");
               price1=price1.replaceAll("-","");

              String price2=object2.getPrice().replaceAll(",","");
           price2=price2.replaceAll("-","");

              return ((Integer)Integer.parseInt(price1)).compareTo((Integer)Integer.parseInt(price2)); 

          }

};
```

But if i execute the statement
    Collections.sort(carsList, comparator);

getting the Exception

Exception:`Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

is happening because of  "-" elements in your array. And when you do this:

```
           price1=price1.replaceAll("-","");
```

the new price1 string contains an empty string ""

leading the following `Integer.parseInt` statement to fail with `NumberFormatExcpetion`.

As `parsetInt` cannot convert an empty string to number.

So one solution is either remove such elements from the array.

Or other solution is define a default values integer for  empty string. Something like:

```
           price1=price1.replaceAll("-","");
           if("".equals(price1))
               price1="0";
```